# Use Azure Powershell to execute a .sql file

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I've seen examples of running a SQL command from Azure Powershell e.g.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=user1;Password=pass1;Connection Timeout=90"
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$query = "CREATE TABLE...." 
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()
```

Is there a way to replace the $query with a reference to an external file that contains an entire SQL script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

20 more mins of searching and I found it.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=user1;Password=pass1;Connection Timeout=90"
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$query = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\...\TestSQL.sql")
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Another option would be to invoke sqlcmd to run the script. An example of iterating through multiple files can be found here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380076/how-to-run-multiple-sql-scripts-in-ssms-against-sql-azure/29402966?noredirect=1#comment46990553_29402966)